# Сравнить содержимое ~100 папок с подпапками

Tags: windows, администрирование, поиск-программ

Есть одна папка (Папка0) с папками (Папки 1, 2, 3, ..., 100, ...), папок 100+ штук, в папках есть файлы и подпапки и их очень много.

Гугл не помог. Есть ли программа, которой можно сравнить их содержимое и получить список совпадений?

К примеру, у меня есть 3 папки с файлами и подпапками:

```
Папка 0 содержит:

Папка1 (Игнорирую название) содержит **ПапкуА** (**ФайлА**, ФайлБ), ПапкуБ(ФайлВ, ФайлГ) и **ФайлД** (Сравниваю структуру содержащуюся внутри папки 1 с содержимым папок 2, 3, ...)

Папка2 (Игнорирую название) содержит **ПапкуА** (**ФайлА**, ФайлЯ), ПапкуУ(ФайлЦ, ФайлЩ) и **ФайлД** (Сравниваю структуру содержащуюся внутри папки 2 с содержимым папок 3, 4, ...)

Папка3 (Игнорирую название) содержит **ПапкуА** (**ФайлА**) (Сравниваю структуру содержащуюся внутри папки 3 с содержимым папок 4, 5, ...)
```

На выходе я хочу получить какой то список с адресами вида:

```
ДискД://Папка0/Папка1/ПапкаА/ФайлА (ПОЛНЫЙ адрес чтобы я это смог найти)
ДискД://Папка0/Папка2/ПапкаА/ФайлА
ДискД://Папка0/Папка3/ПапкаА/ФайлА

ДискД://Папка0/Папка1/ФайлД
ДискД://Папка0/Папка2/ФайлД
```

Upd: Примерный алгоритм того как это должно работать:

1. Берем список папок. Те 100+ папок, в сравнении названия этих 100 папок не учитываем, сравниваем только содержимое.
2. Получаем типа полное дерево файлов в каждой из папок.
3. Сравниваем деревья.
4. Отобразить совпавшие адреса файлов. Если совпадений 3, выводим 3, если 100, выводим 100, и.т.п.

Upd2: Приведу пример еще проще. Я беру содержимое Папка1 и копирую в Папка2. Как винда копирует. Со слиянием папок. Если есть совпадения, винда выведет диалог о замене. Потом я беру содержимое которое уже общее папки1 и папки2 и копирую в Папка3. Опять винда копирует, если есть совпадения выводит диалог о замене. Вот такие совпадения которые винда БЫ обозначила как запрос на замену мне и нужны. Только с сохранением оригинальной структуры папок.

Comment: не ясна логика получаемого ответа: нужен список файлов присутствующих во всех трёх папках? либо по каким параметрам выводить результаты?

Comment: @ganz Есть куча, прям реально куча папок, файлов, подпапок и.т.п. Нужно найти совпадения, прям просто любые совпадения адресов не учитывая название корневой папки, все совпадения какие есть, их... сколько то и искать их мануально я откровенно задолбаюсь. Не учитывая название корневой папки (Папка1, 2, 3). В примере у меня во всех 3 папках была папкаА (Это типа такое название папки) в которой был файлА(а это название файла, да). И мне эти адреса файлов вывело. А ФайлД был только в 1 и во 2, вывело их.

Comment: а Папка1/ПапкаА/ФайлА и Папка3/ПапкаБ/ФайлА - совпадение? а Папка3/ПапкаА/ФайлА и Папка3/ПапкаБ/ФайлА?

Comment: @nörbörnën Приведу пример еще проще. Я беру содержимое Папка1 и копирую в Папка2. Как винда копирует. Со слиянием папок. Если есть совпадения, винда выведет диалог о замене. Потом я беру содержимое общее папки1 и папки2 и копирую в Папка3. Опять винда копирует, если есть совпадения выводит диалог о замене. Вот такие совпадения которые винда БЫ обозначила как замену мне и нужны.

Comment: Мне кажется, такое проще самому написать, чем найти...

Comment: Вас интересуют совпадения путей или совпадения файлов тоже важны? По идее, это задача для RSYNC в режиме dry-run, или даже для diff

Comment: @gbg, они разве работают с произвольным числом каталогов?

Comment: @gbg файлы типа разные будут скорее всего. Либо одинаковые. Но могут быть и разные, с одинаковыми названиями. Интересует только совпадение [путь внутри папки/название файла.txt]. Хмм, написать самому... Где можно взять код для получения полного древа папок/файлов с неизвестным уровнем вложенности? Типа AHK или питон мб. Оу, кажется придумал как это самому написать, реально да. Только нужен код для неизвестного уровня вложенности.

Comment: В linux/unix `diff -r` умеет рекурсивно сравнивать содержимое каталогов. Можете поиграться с разбором его вывода, чтобы принимать удовлетворяющее вашей задаче решение

Comment: @avp метки... метки... есть только винда. А так я уже написал.

Comment: @Gh0sTG0, неужели никто не удосужился перенести grep туда? Наверняка в [msys](https://www.msys2.org/) должен быть

Comment: Ну если просто сравнить, то воз и маленькая тележка - многочисленные diff - утилиты вроде WinMerge или "синхронизировать каталоги" в Total Commander.  А вот если сохранить результат сравнения в нужный вид - тут видимо только кодить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написал сам, писал на непопулярном здесь ahk.

```
    DBFileName := "D:\data.db"
    DB := New SQLiteDB
    If !DB.OpenDB(DBFileName) {
       MsgBox, 16, SQLite Error, % "Msg:`t" . DB.ErrorMsg . "`nCode:`t" . DB.ErrorCode
    }


    SQL := "DELETE FROM file_structure;" ; обнулил специально созданную под это дело таблицу в бд
    If !DB.Exec(SQL)
    {
            MsgBox, 16, SQLite Error, % "Msg:`t" . DB.ErrorMsg . "`nCode:`t" . DB.ErrorCode
    }


    yourFolder = D:\folder_way
    Loop, % yourFolder "\*", 0, 1
    {
        ToolTip, %A_Index%
        full_adr := A_LoopFileFullPath
        inter_adr := SubStr(full_adr, InStr(full_adr, "\",,, 7) + 1) ; определил правую часть адреса.
        StringReplace, inter_adr, inter_adr, ', '', All
        StringReplace, full_adr, full_adr, ', '', All
        SQL := "INSERT INTO file_structure VALUES('" . full_adr . "', '" . inter_adr . "');"
        If !DB.Exec(SQL)
            MsgBox, 16, SQLite Error, % "Msg:`t" . DB.ErrorMsg . "`nCode:`t" . DB.ErrorCode
    }


    SQL := 
    (
"SELECT a.*
FROM file_structure a
JOIN (SELECT full_adr, inter_adr, COUNT(*)
FROM file_structure 
GROUP BY inter_adr
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.inter_adr = b.inter_adr
ORDER BY a.inter_adr"
    )

    Result := ""
    If !DB.GetTable(SQL, Result)
        MsgBox, 16, SQLite Error: GetTable, % "Msg:`t" . DB.ErrorMsg . "`nCode:`t" . DB.ErrorCode
    Else
    {
        oldCheck := ""
        newCheck := ""
        Excel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application") ; вставляю в эксель для дальнейшей ручной обработки.
        Cell := Excel.Cells(Excel.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Offset(1, 0)
        index = 0
        For Each, Row In Result.Rows
        {
            IfWinActive, ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE
            {
                ToolTip, %A_Index%
                newCheck := Row[2] ; newCheck и oldCheck являются правой частью адреса

                if (newCheck <> oldCheck)
                {
                    index += 2 ; если новый файл не совпадает с предыдущим делаю пропуск
                }
                oldCheck := newCheck

                Cell.Offset(index, 0).Value := Row[1]
                index += 1
            } else {
                MsgBox, ERROR!!!
            }
        }
        Excel := Cell := ""
    }

    DB.CloseDB()
```

Answer (score 1):

Если устравивает решение на джаве, то это выглядит примерно так (в агрументы метода main передаете список корневых каталогов, которые хотите проверить) :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        for (String rootDirPath : args) {

            System.out.println("===================" + rootDirPath + "===================");

            Map<String, Set<String>> pathMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (File file : new File(rootDirPath).listFiles()) {
                final int len = file.isDirectory() ? file.getName().length() + 1 : 0;
                Map<String, Set<String>> collect = listFiles(file).stream()
                        .map(f -> f.getPath().substring(rootDirPath.length() + len + 1, f.getPath().length()))
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(f -> file.getName(),
                                Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toSet())));
                pathMap.putAll(collect);
            }

            Set<String> pathSet = new HashSet<>();
            for (Set<String> set : pathMap.values()) pathSet.addAll(set);
            for (String path : pathSet) print(getPath(path, pathMap));

        }

    }

    private static void print(List<String> result) {
        if (result.size() < 2) return;
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
    }

    private static List<String> getPath(String path, Map<String, Set<String>> pathMap) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : pathMap.keySet()) {
            if (pathMap.get(p).contains(path)) result.add(p + File.separator + path);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<File> listFiles(File file) {
        final List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            for (File includeFile : file.listFiles()) {
                fileList.addAll(listFiles(includeFile));
            }
        }
        else fileList.add(file);
        return fileList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но уже все сделал. Даже сам об этом ответ опубликовал, да.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, подобные задачи нужно решать способом выявления неуникальных имен путем установки их ключами ассоциативной структуры данных: ассоциативный массив, список, словарь, таблица в БД или табличном редакторе с одним столбиком уникальных ключей.

В общем, "слева" ключи (имена файлов), "справа" - список, массив из путей или строка через разделитель.

Алгоритм такой:

- Проходим все файлы всех папок.
- Создаем запись в ассоциативной структуре с ключом == имени файла, если такой записи нет.
- Добавляем в значение путь к файлу.

По итогу имеем структуру вида:

```
{
  ['filename1' => ['path1']],
  ['filename2' => ['path2','path3','path6']],
  ['filename3' => ['path1','path5','path110',...]],
  ['filename4' => ['path2','path7','path200',...]],
  ...
}
```

Потом перебираете полученное и значения, в которых больше одного пути, и выводите, как вам нужно.

Сей алгоритм позволит вывести все совпадения за  `<= 2n` итераций, где n - кол-во файлов во всех папках.

Answer (score -2):

Вот решение на питоне (http://python.org), заменить значения dir1 итд на нужные названия папок

```
dir1='c:/'
dir2='c:/'
dir3='c:/'
import filecmp
res12=filecmp.dircmp(dir1, dir2, ignore=None).common_files
res13=filecmp.dircmp(dir1,dir3).common_files
for it in res12:
  if it in res13:
     print(it)
```

если не ищет не корректно то нужно будет работать с os.walk

Comment: Эмм... Серьезно? Первая строка моего вопроса про 100+ папок, дальше идут просто примеры... Ну не писать же мне в примере 100+ папок? dir1= dir2= dir3=? И пусть даже так, где сравнение 2 и 3 папок? Вдруг там есть свое совпадение? А if it in res13 там зачем? Мне нужны ЛЮБЫЕ совпадения, в ЛЮБЫХ папках. И да, в ЛЮБЫХ комбинациях и в ЛЮБЫХ количествах совпадений, однако... Может быть файл совпадает в 2 папках, может во всей сотне...

Comment: dir1 dir2 dir3 пути к исходным папкам, то есть к тем в которых находятся твои 100+-, модуль file cmp, сравнивает содержимое двух директорий, функция common_files возвращает список файлов присутствующих в обеих директориях, if it in использовано в качестве заглушки  для получения списка третей папки. Однако, я запамятывал обрабатывает ли filecmp директории рекурсивно поэтому и оставил отсылку к os.walk

Comment: понял свою ошибку, пошел править, да. Есть ОДНА общая папка, в которой было 100+ подпапок. Подпапки 1го уровня (те самые 100+ которые лежат в ОДНОЙ папке), их названия я игнорил.

Comment: Ладно, в любом случае я это уже напрограммировал и обработал, так что тема уже не актуальна.

Comment: ну хоть минусов отхватил

Comment: Чего нибудь поменяй в ответе, попробую тебе обнулить, так не дает

Comment: Забей, сам виноват: не внятно объяснил.